# Query still going very slowly

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with 2 million records.

Here is the table

```
comments
---------
    +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | commentid   | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | parentid    | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | refno       | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | createdate  | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
    | remoteip    | varchar(80)   | YES  |     |         |                |
    | fingerprint | varchar(50)   | YES  |     |         |                |
    | locid       | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
    | clubid      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | profileid   | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
    | userid      | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
    | global      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | official    | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | legacyuser  | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
    | mediaid     | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | status      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 1       |                |
    | comment     | varchar(4000) | YES  |     |         |                |
    | likes       | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | dislikes    | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | import      | int(11)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
    | author      | varchar(50)   | YES  |     |         |                |
    +-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now this query against 2 million records takes 6 to 7 seconds:

```
select * from comments where (locid=2085 or global=1) and status>0 order by createdate desc limit 20;
```

**I decided to add an index to locid and it still produces results in 6 to 7 seconds**

I could have used a sqlfiddle but it would have been unneccessary since the basis of this question pertains to performance and I'm not adding 2mil records to sqlfiddle.

**Are there any strategies or implementations which can get this query into the 3 seconds range?**

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

This is my explain show table.

```
        | comments | CREATE TABLE `comments` (
      `commentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `refno` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `createdate` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `remoteip` varchar(80) DEFAULT '',
      `fingerprint` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
      `locid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `clubid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `profileid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `userid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `global` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `official` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `legacyuser` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `mediaid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
      `comment` varchar(4000) DEFAULT '',
      `likes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `dislikes` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `import` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `author` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`commentid`),
      KEY `comments_locid` (`locid`),
      KEY `comments_userid` (`userid`),
      KEY `idx_legacyusers` (`legacyuser`),
      KEY `profile_index` (`profileid`),
      KEY `comments_createdate` (`createdate`),
      KEY `compound_for_comments` (`locid`,`global`,`status`),
      KEY `global` (`global`),
      KEY `status` (`status`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3848451 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: There's good optimization advice (and diagnosis tools) out there worth checking out, see e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Obviously all columns used in the `WHERE` clause have to be index somehow. Tyke a look at mysql#s `EXPLAIN` feature. It helps to understand what is going on.

Comment: K ill look into explain

Comment: How big is the result set? And what indexes are defined? `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` will provide better information than `DESCRIBE`

Comment: Using `OR` is usually the kiss of death for performance. Is there any way you can restructure the table to make it possible to query against a single index instead of having to combine two result sets and sort them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most DBs, especially MySQL, are notoriously bad with `or`.

You can eradicate the `or` by splitting the query into a `union` with each half handling one side of the `or`, like this:

```
select * from (
    select * from comments
    where locid = 2085
    and status > 0
    union
    select * from comments
    where global = 1
    and status > 0) x
order by createdate desc
limit 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'order by' is causing this to take so much time. Remove order by and see if it is changed . You can order by the Primary Key because the later records have bigger assigned Primary Key which is a key and faster.
Other option is to use an engine that is stored on memory rather than hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```sql
select distinct * from (

    select * from (
        select * from comments where locid=2085 and status>0 order by commentid desc limit 20
    ) t1

     union all

      select * from (
         select * from comments where global=1 and status>0 order by commentid desc limit 20
     ) t2

 ) t
order by commentid desc 
limit 20
```

with indexes on (locid, status) and (global, status). (status, global) might be better than (global, status) - it depends on which column is more selective.

That only works if `createdate` is sorted equal to `commentid`. Othewise you would need indexes like (locid, status, createdate) and order by `createdate`.

Comment: This looks good. In the future, you can replace distinct with a union instead of union all with a distinct

Comment: Always put the '=' part first.  That is, `(global, status)` is more useful than `(status, global)`.

Comment: @slicks1,  `UNION` has to sort the result to remove duplicates. `DISTINCT` has to do that too. In my case i'm already explicitely sorting the result in the outer select, so i prefered to use `DISTICT` there. But because my subselect is limited to 40 rows, it' doesn't really matter.

Comment: @RickJames, if `global` is a boolean flag and 90% of rows are global and 90% of rows have `status=0` then status would be more selective for this query.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be even faster than the queries mentioned in two answer so far:

```
SELECT  c.*
    FROM  ( 
              ( SELECT  commentid, createdate
                    FROM  comments
                    WHERE  locid=2085
                      AND  status > 0
                    ORDER BY  createdate DESC
                    LIMIT  20 
              )
            UNION  DISTINCT 
              ( SELECT  commentid, createdate
                    FROM  comments
                    WHERE  global=1
                      AND  status > 0
                    ORDER BY  createdate DESC
                    LIMIT  20 
              )
            ORDER BY  createdate DESC
            LIMIT  20 
          ) x
    JOIN  comments c USING (commentid);
```

With both of these "covering" indexes:

```
INDEX(locid,  status, createdate, commentid)
INDEX(global, status, createdate, commentid)
```

*(based on later info)* Since (global=1) is usually true and (status>0) is usually false, the following may be better.  (There is a question of whether `DESC` adds a monkey wrench.)

```
INDEX(locid,  createdate, status, commentid)
INDEX(global, createdate, status, commentid)
```

There is still a risk with `global`.  If it is 'usually' `1`, then the above indexes may not be optimal.

This formulation will be faster because the subqueries will be entirely in the index ("covering"), rather than lugging around all the columns (`*`).  That does require an extra `SELECT`, but it is an efficient `JOIN` on the `PRIMARY KEY` of only 20 rows.  If your table ever became too big to cache, this would be a big performance bonus.

I was explicit with `UNION DISTINCT` on the assumption that you would get dups otherwise.  If not, then `UNION ALL` would be faster.

Schema critique:

- Use appropriately sized `INTs` -- `INT` is 4 bytes; `TINYINT` is only 1; etc.
- Use `UNSIGNED` where appropriate (especially, for ids and counts).
- Use `NOT NULL` where appropriate.
- Don't index flags (`global`? `status`?) by themselves; the index is very unlikely to be used.
- How many distinct values does `status` hold?  If `status>0` can be replaced by `status=1`, my suggested index will work even better.

Making the data smaller may speed up this query (and others).

Comment: I would agree, if the the subselects weren't limited to 20 rows. But with LIMIT 20 it doesn't really (measurable) matter. Much more important is that an index can support all conditions and the select order. BTW it seams that MySQL can not use an index for `ORDER BY .. DESC` if the required column is not on the first place. So `LIMIT` in the subselects (in my answer too) might be almost useles and Bohemians answer can perform equal with less complexity.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - "can not use an index .. DESC" -- I think it is more complex than that.  There are cases where the index is effective.

Comment: `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';` is a handy way to see whether only 20+ rows were scanned versus the entire set.